# Oracle ADF : Increasing BarGraph Size and Bars Size

Tags: css, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

We have developed web application using Oracle ADF. In our application we have a page with a graph as show below.

[image]

Actually we need to increase bar graph size in terms of height, width and Bars size also.

Problem 1: For this we have found some solution from oracle documents we can increase graph size using inlinestyle="height=400px;widht=600px;"(This is working fine).
But This is browser dependent. Please let us know if there is any class to increase graph size. .

Problem 2: But we are unable to find solution for increasing the size of bars(lines). Please Help us in increasing bar's size as follows

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the graph inside an stretchable layout component (such as the center facet of a panelStretchLayout component).
This should stretch the chart to fill out the area available.
See for example: http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/faces/components/barChart.jspx

Comment: Hello Shay. I tried with your solution. But it is not working. Actually I have created this graph inside .jsff. I have tested your solution both in .jsff and .jsf page. But am not seeing any difference.

Comment: If you are using an 11g version of ADF - did you set the graph dynamicResize property to be dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

You can control the layout of your graph bars through ADF Skinning.
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35521_01/apirefs.111230/e17498/toc.htm

If skinning is not a familiar subject, I would recommend to start from here:
https://blogs.oracle.com/jdevotnharvest/entry/how_to_learn_adf_skinning